# Alternative of Object.assign(...array)

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

Assume we have array of objects.

Calling `Object.assign(...array)` makes an inheritance among those objects where object with index `i` override existing properties in object with index `i-1`

For example:

```js
var array=[{interf:'IPerson',name:'Someone'},{clss:'Person',name:'Ahmed'},{student:true}];
console.log(
    Object.assign(...array) // Object.assign(array[0],array[1],array[2])
)
```

Now, using Babel with the proposed object spread syntax, we can do this statically :

```
{...array[0],...array[1],...array[2]} // spread used for each object not for array
```

**How to do that dynamically?**

There is overlap of context of "spread syntax". I mean how to use spread syntax for both:

- For the Array to spread elements.
- For the output literal object `{}` to make inheritance

?

I tried `{...array}` and it returns `{0:<array[0]>,1:<array[1]>,2:<array[2]>}` which is **not** the same output as `Object.assign(...array)`.

Comment: ES7 is done and released, object spread is not part of it. Just say "proposed object spread syntax", don't say ES7.

Comment: Assignment has nothing to do with inheritance. Use the terms "extend" or "mixin".

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Do you think we should have a tag for each of those proposals? (created on demand)

Comment: Tough one, I don't know if anyone would use them, but could be nice

Comment: can somebody suggest an alternative for this with a snippet?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are looking for

```
var obj = Object.assign({}, ...array)
```

that creates a new object instead of mutating `array[0]`.

Comment: Would you happen to have an IE11 safe alternative for `.assign()` laying around? Looking for that now because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/object-assign-function-object-javascript) (See requirements)

Comment: No, you can safely use `Object.assign` in IE11, just [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Comment: would you try with: let array = [1, {a:1,b:2}, [3,4,5]]; the result isn't trivial

Comment: @alex OP has an array of objects. It doesn't make sense to use this code for arrays containing other arrays or numbers. What do you mean by "trivial", what output did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the method you're looking for is .concat()

Returns a new array which is a merge of the target and the source.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the method you are looking for, as mentioned above, is `.concat()`, which creates a copy of an array and extends it with another one.

```js
var a1 = [1,2,3], a2 = [];

a2 = a2.concat(a1);

// or ES5 shorten alternative 
// var a1 = [1,2,3], a2 = [].concat(a1);

// or better ES6 shorten alternative 
// a2 = [...a1];

a2.push(4);

console.log(a1, a2);

// a1 -> [1,2,3], a2 -> [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign Objects with array object:

```js
var a = {
  'name': 'Ajay'
}

var b = {
  approvers: [{
    id: '12'
  }]
}

var c = Object.assign(a, b);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: The variable `a` and `b` are type of an object and not an array